# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Event Fire too many times

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am having problems stopping the event firing a second time after selecting a a value in the drop down combo. The event opens a dialog which tells the user if they want to save it with a yes or no option.

I have a grid view has 2 columns on it:
[image]

My code is below.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Team> teamList = new List<Team>();
        List<Team_Colour> teamColourList = new List<Team_Colour>();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test A", Colour_ID = 1});
            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test B", Colour_ID = 2 });
            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test C", Colour_ID = 3 });
            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test D", Colour_ID = 4 });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = teamList;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            cb.HeaderText = "Colour";

            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 1, Colour_Name = "None" });
            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 2, Colour_Name = "Green" });
            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 3, Colour_Name = "Blue" });
            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 4, Colour_Name = "Red" });


            cb.DataSource = teamColourList;
            cb.DisplayMember = "Colour_Name";
            cb.ValueMember = "Colour_ID";
            cb.DataPropertyName = "Colour_ID";


            dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, cb);

        }

        private void DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure", "Saving", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click a new value in the drop down for the first row, the event is fired as expected:
[image]

When I click yes the dialog goes away but the dropdown still looks like it's selected as it appears different than the others:
[image]

As soon as I try to select an arrow of another dropdown, it is fired again like its not been unfocused.
[image]

How do I stop if being focused after I clicked yes during the first dialog box?

Comment: I will not deny that the event fires twice. It fires “once” when the user “clicks on a cell” and when the user “leaves a cell.” This may be the nature of the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event, however, I have to ask… are you sure this is the event you want to use to “SAVE” the data?

Comment: If the data is saved in a Data Base, then saving the data “every time” the user clicks on a cell or changes the value in a cell… well… that just seems like you may be clobbering the data base. Are you sure an “external” mechanism, like a “save” button or when the focus “leaves” the grid itself may be a better approach? It just seems odd to save the data every time the user makes a single change.

Comment: It will need to be saved if user clicks yes. Its one of the requirements on the job I am working on.

Comment: Then you may want to consider using a different event, like the grids `CellValueChanged` event. It only fires once when the user makes a change in a cell then “leaves” that cell.

Comment: Thanks John. I found a solution with using both events. If I just use CellValueChanged only then I lose the functionality of the message box appearing as soon as user clicks an option on dropdown. User will need to click away for the message box to come up.

Comment: I think you want the `dgv.RowValidating` event instead, which gives the option to `Cancel` the edit.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution. I am using both CellValueChanged and CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged to make it work. My code is below.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Team> teamList = new List<Team>();
        List<Team_Colour> teamColourList = new List<Team_Colour>();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test A", Colour_ID = 1});
            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test B", Colour_ID = 2 });
            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test C", Colour_ID = 3 });
            teamList.Add(new Team { name = "Test D", Colour_ID = 4 });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = teamList;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            cb.HeaderText = "Colour";

            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 1, Colour_Name = "None" });
            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 2, Colour_Name = "Green" });
            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 3, Colour_Name = "Blue" });
            teamColourList.Add(new Team_Colour { Colour_ID = 4, Colour_Name = "Red" });


            cb.DataSource = teamColourList;
            cb.DisplayMember = "Colour_Name";
            cb.ValueMember = "Colour_ID";
            cb.DataPropertyName = "Colour_ID";


            dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, cb);

        }

        private void DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure", "Saving", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing by using ONLY the `CellValueChanged` event. In fact, using this approach, if the user is expected to “type” values into a NON combo box cell… you will have a bigger problem. Try it yourself… try to edit one of the other non-combo box cells.

Comment: i used CellValueChanged event. As mentioned in previous comment, messagebox only appears when i click away from the combo box which won't work as I need messagebox to come up right away unless I am misunderstanding you and theses a way to achieve it with CellValueChanged. To deal with non combo box cells, I will add code to handle the event only if it's the combo box column id.

Comment: If, inside the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` the code is calling the grids `CommitEdit` ONLY when the “combo box” is changed, then that should work.

Comment: HOWEVER, as I stated earlier, IF you call the DB to save these changes EVERY TIME one of the grid cell value’s change… and this IS a “requirement”… then I would question who is making this requirement. I can assure you the DB manager is not going to support this pounding of the DB. The whole idea of updating the DB every time a user changes one of the cells… is frowned upon in almost all cases. However, If this is a requirement you have to meet, then go for it.